# Best Approach to Detecting Breakpoints in Continuous Treatment-Outcome Relationship?

Tags: machine-learning, causality, propensity-scores, change-point, observational-study

I am currently conducting research to understand the relationship between a continuous treatment variable and a continuous outcome variable. To mitigate confounding and selection bias, I am employing the Inverse Probability of Treatment Weights (IPTW) method, which is calculated based on relevant covariates.

My hypothesis is that there might be breakpoints (whose levels are currently unknown) within my treatment variable, influencing a change in the mean level of my outcome variable. However, as a beginner in this field, I'm struggling to determine the most statistically rigorous approach for this analysis.

Am I on the right track with my understanding, and would it be appropriate to apply a weighted CHAID regression tree using weights derived from the IPTW method? This algorithm is pretty good at identifying simple, interpretable thresholds. Would you suggest other method, if this is inappropriate?